# Material 2 datatable dynamic row template #angular4

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Does any one have any idea on how to pass templates to data table column from typescript file ?. I am trying to achieve that using interpolation but its not helping. any ideas?

Thanks,
Arun kumar

Comment: You need to define them as components themselves and append them to the host element using the componentfactoryresolver. This is too large an implementation for one SO answer. but this docs section explains it https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader, your simpler alternative is to just define all possible columns in the template and then use ngIf to make the appropriate ones appear.

Comment: Please post the code snippets you are using, or provide a plunker example [here's a template to get started](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue). You can read more about [how to ask a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I'm understanding your question, but maybe try something like this:

```
<!-- Generic column definition -->
<ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [cdkColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
  <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>{{ column.header }}</md-header-cell>
  <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{ column.cell(row) }}</md-cell>
</ng-container>
```

And then to select your columns

```
/** Table columns */
columns = [
  { columnDef: 'userId',    header: 'ID',       cell: (row: UserData) => `${row.id}`        },
  { columnDef: 'userName',  header: 'Name',     cell: (row: UserData) => `${row.name}`      },
  { columnDef: 'progress',  header: 'Progress', cell: (row: UserData) => `${row.progress}%` }
];

/** Column definitions in order */
displayedColumns = this.columns.map(x => x.columnDef);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
export class MyDatatableComponent implements OnInit {
    displayedColumns = ['Id', 'Name', 'Address'];
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
    }
}

<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let cols of displayedColumns" [matColumnDef]="cols">

        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{cols}} </mat-header-cell>

        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row[cols]}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>

    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```